# Repeater Not Retrieving from SQL Server Whilst Inside a Drop-down Div

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Below, is a list item on my navbar. When I hover over it, it displays a sub-menu of the different sports.

```
<li class="w3-dropdown-hover">
                            <a href="Sports.aspx">Sports</a>
                            <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
                                <a href="#">GAA</a>
                                <a href="#">Camogie</a>
                                <a href="#">Ladies Football</a>
                                <a href="#">Richmond Soccer</a>
                                <a href="#">Fishing</a>
                                <a href="#">Restocking Association</a>
                                <a href="#">Walking Club</a>
                                <a href="#">Gun Club</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

I have added the below code to retrieve the different Sports teams from an SQL Server database, and display those team names as the drop-down menu items.

```
 <li class="w3-dropdown-hover">
                            <a href="Sports.aspx">Sports</a>
                            <div class="w3-dropdown-content w3-white w3-card-4">
                                <asp:Repeater ID="repSport" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <a href="#"><%#Eval("Team_Name") %></a>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:Repeater>
                            </div>
```

Code Behind:

```
        SqlConnection connR;
    string connectionStringR = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[
        "BallinoraDBConnectionString1"].ConnectionString;
    connR = new SqlConnection(connectionStringR);
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Sport", connR);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    repSport.DataSource = dt;
    repSport.DataBind();
```

However, when I add this code no sub-menu items are displayed.

To test if the repeater retrieves the names, I placed it in a seperate div, and it displayed the team names.

It is only when I place the repeater in the  below, that nothing is being displayed.

Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: Your Repeater has ID = repSportDesc, in your code behind you bind the data to repSport. Is that correct?

Comment: @WoutervanVegchel I changed it, but still no change

Comment: What does the datasource look like when you debug it?

Comment: Perhaps you can try using DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Team_Name") instead of Eval("Team_Name").